# Python to Print No. of Characters for Multiple word documents using Python-docx or any other Library(selecting documents by GUI Dialog Box)

Tags: python, python-3.x, ms-word, character, python-docx

I Tried to print no. of characters in a word document using Python-docx

```
import docx

doc = docx.Document("example.docx")
all_paras = doc.paragraphs
len(all_paras)
```

But This code is only printing no. of paragraphs in the word document.

How can I print no. of characters in the word docuement ?

Python-docx is not mandatory any other library is also fine.

Q2:-
How to print no. of characters in Multiple Word Documents ? I also want to store no. of word documents as variables.

If possible, can I select multiple word documents using **GUI dialog box** and then *store no. of characters for each document as multiple variables ?*

example:- I select 5 word documents using GUI dialog box.

I want to store no. of characters in each of the word documents

```
a = no.of characters in word document 1
   
b = no.of characters in word document 2
    
c = no.of characters in word document 3
    
d = no.of characters in word document 4

e = no.of characters in word document 5
```

Then, if I want to `print(a)`, then no. of characters in word  document 1 should be printed.

If I want to `print(d)`, then no. of characters in word document 4 should be printed

Note:- Here, Printing the characters is not important. storing them as variables is important

Dialog Box in tkinter is also ok, or any other is also ok.

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```py
    import docx
    doc = docx.Document("example.docx")
    
    # Option 1
    chars = [chars for paragraph in doc.paragraphs for chars in paragraph.text if chars != ' ' ]
    num_chars =len(chars)
    
    # Explanation list comprehension option 1
    chars_option1 = []
    for paragraph in doc.paragraphs:
      for chars in paragraph.text:
        if chars != ' ':
          chars_option1.append(chars)
          
        
    # Option 2
    paragraphs_chars = [list(paragraph.text) for paragraph in doc.paragraphs]
    wsx = [char for chars in paragraphs_chars for char in chars if char != ' ']
    num_chars_opc2 = len(wsx)
    
    print(num_chars, len(chars_option1), num_chars_opc2)
```

```py
    from collections import Counter
    def get_charaters(document):
      doc = docx.Document(document)
      chars = [chars for paragraph in doc.paragraphs for chars in paragraph.text if chars != ' ' ]
      num_chars =len(chars)
      return (chars, num_chars)
    
    # single document
    chars, num_chars = get_charaters("example.docx")
    print(chars, num_chars)
    
    # multiple document
    for document_path in {"example.docx", "example2.docx", "example3.docx"}:
      chars, num_chars = get_charaters(document_path)
      print(chars, num_chars)
    
    # Count num of characters
    c = Counter(chars)
    print(c)
```

Comment: Your code is printing the characters. But i want it in numbers example:- 40 characters or 1054 characters, like that

Comment: I also want to print no. of characters in multiple word documents and I want to select multiple word documents using GUI Dialog Box

Comment: I have edited the code to make it clearer. You can create a function that uses the document path as parameter to process multiple documents.

Comment: can you edit your code for multiple word documents ?

Comment: Hi Noob, 
I have edited the code for multiple documents.